# 1366 incorrect integer value: error when importing data from csv into mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I am trying to import data from csv into MySQL using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. For an integer column called "count" that has all null values I am getting the error 1366 incorrect integer value:

I have tried `count = IF(@count='',NULL,@count)`

**CREATE TABLE MySchema.response:**

```
CREATE TABLE MySchema.response
(
`id` int,
`name` varchar(500), 
`count` int,
);
```

**loading data into table:**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/response.csv' 
INTO TABLE MySchema.response
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' optionally ENCLOSED by '"' 
ignore 1 lines
(id, name, @count)
SET count = IF(@count='',NULL,@count)
```

**sample csv file data**

```
1,abc,

2,xyz,
```

Comment: I am encountering the same problem right now. Have you managed to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to define the var, see correct `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` statement below:

```
root@localhost [test]> SHOW CREATE TABLE `Response`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: Response
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Response` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)

root@localhost [test]> LOAD DATA INFILE '~/Desktop/data.csv' INTO TABLE Response FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'   (id, name, @count) SET count = IF(@count = '', NULL, @count);

root@localhost [test]> SELECT * FROM `Response`;
+------+------+-------+
| id   | name | count |
+------+------+-------+
|    1 | abc  |  NULL |
|    2 | xyz  | 12345 |
+------+------+-------+
```

File `data.csv`

```
1,abc,
2,xyz,12345
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo... I have defined the var

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but it may help someone with this same issue.

You should check for line breaks (somehow MySQL parse the third text column this way).
Also make sure your CSV file doesn't have BOM (bit order mark).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'd:/response.csv' 
INTO TABLE response
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
IGNORE 0 LINES
(id, NAME, @count)
SET COUNT = IF(@count='' OR @count='\r' OR @count='\n' OR @count='\r\n' ,NULL,@count)
```

> 1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings
>
> Query: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'd:/response.csv' INTO TABLE response
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' optionally ENCLOSED by '"'  ignore 1 lines...
>
> 1 row(s) affected
>
> Execution Time : 0.004 sec Transfer Time  : 0.006 sec Total Time     :
> 0.011 sec

If your CSV file has all null values for COUNT, this simpler way will work:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'd:/response.csv' 
INTO TABLE response 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, NAME, @dummy)
```